# Watir::Browser#execute_script and "Element no longer valid"

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, watir-webdriver

I'm writing some automation for a website of ours in Internet Explorer (it has to be IE :< ) and I ran into some issues with execute_script. I need to move a vertical splitbar over 200px so it doesn't move certain elements off the page, making them unclickable. To do this I figured I would use the `Watir::Browser#execute_script` functionality. The idea would be to change the style tag to the correct coordinates. Unfortunately I haven't been able to get it to work due to "Element is no longer valid" errors. Here are the two cases I tried and their respective errors.

First, I tried just getting the style attribute (the one I need to change) via a javascript script.

```
script = <<-JS
  return arguments[0].style
JS

browser.execute_script(script, aw.watir.div(class: 'x-vsplitbar'))
```

This gives me `Uncaught exception: Element is no longer valid`

I also tried changing the element's tag as well.

```
element = aw.watir.div(class: 'x-vsplitbar')
style = element.style.gsub('200', '400')
script = "return arguments[0].style = '#{style}'"
browser.execute_script(script, element)
```

This just gave me a sweet error `JavaScript error (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError)`

The script in this example comes out to:

```
return arguments[0].style = 'HEIGHT: 897px; WIDTH: 5px; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 400px; TOP: 50px'
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I followed [this](https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2013/07/10/changing-an-elements-attribute-value/) guide.

Another solution would be to use Watir to simulate the dragging action needed but I couldn't figure out how to drag the bar to the right.

Comment: What do you want actually?? Do you want to set style attribute of the element as `HEIGHT: 897px; WIDTH: 5px; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 400px; TOP: 50px`??

Comment: Yes, although I couldn't get either of the scripts working. I tried an example "change the button text on google.com" test and that worked fine.

Comment: The exception sounds like the element, `aw.watir.div(class: 'x-vsplitbar')` is not being found correctly. Are you sure you located the element correctly - ie what is `aw.watir.div(class: 'x-vsplitbar').exists?`? Can you also give the full exception? The error message isn't one I recall seeing in Watir.

Comment: It shows up which i hilarious. If I debug the script in RubyMine and stop it right before the execute script it says that it does exist. Also for shits and giggles I tried a couple test scripts on the page. When I run `return document` and do not pass the element to the script as an argument it give me a `Element is no longer valid` error.

Comment: If you want to set style attribute don't use return just try as `browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style' 'HEIGHT: 897px; WIDTH: 5px; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 400px; TOP: 50px', element)` and let me know

Comment: @SaurabhGaur, is probably right. It looks like the IEDriver is not returning what Watir expects. Watir is thinking the returned value is an element and tries to create an `Element` object.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Works but it didn't do what I wanted. (it doesn't expand it for some reason.) Thanks for the help guys it looks like I have more to look into to make this work. It did change the proper element attributes but the bar didn't move. I think I might need to force a redraw if the element.

Comment: Then you need to verify it at browser console by pressing f12 at that page with correct JavaScript before executing it using selenium

Comment: I did, and it does change the values I wanted so thats a step in the right direction. There is just so wonky javascript stuff going on on this page, so I'm sure it can be done how I want just have to find the right hack to make it work. Whenever I seem to work with IE things that should work don't, and theres always some stupid hack to fix it. F12 is the only reason I know anything about this stupid application.